# Probability example for homework

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There's a highway between two towns. To reach the other, people must pay 10 dollars for cars and 25 dollars for bigger vehicles. How big income can we expect if the 60 percent of vehicles are cars and there are 25 incoming vehicles per hour?

What kind of distribution does it follow, and how to calculate with that?

Comment: One can interpret the problem as *deterministic* (exactly $25$ vehicles, of which exactly $15$ are cars, and $10$ are bigger). This is unreasonable. But we can interpret the problem as saying the **mean** number of vehicles is $25$. This tells us very little about the *distribution* of the number of vehicles, but together with the probability breakdown for the two types, it is enough for finding the mean income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a discrete distribution.

$\text{P(Vehicle is car)} = 0.6$ and

$\text{P(Vehicle is a bigger vehicle)} = 0.4$

Expected revenue per vehicle is:

$\text{E(Revenue per vehicle)} = \text{P(Vehicle is car)} (\text{Revenue from car}) + 
\text{P(Vehicle is a bigger vehicle)} (\text{Revenue from a bigger vehicles})$

Thus, total expected revenue is:

$\text{Total expected revenue} = (\text{Total number of vehicles}) \text{E(Revenue per vehicle)}$

Comment: If only I could memorize the work of expected values...thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, among  $25$ incoming vehicles per hour, $25\cdot 60%=15$ are cars

and the number of bigger vehicles be $25-15=10$

Now we can calculate payment from the $10$ cars and  the rest $10$  bigger vehicles

Comment: Oh...it was easier than it seemed...thanks!

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt, welcome. But not sure about the linkage with probability